# Dynamic MySQL Statements with MySQL Variables, possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-select-db

I've been thinking, might it be possible to dynamically change MySQL select-statement with variables.

ex.

```
SET @infile=1;
SELECT * 
IF( @infile )
INTO OUTFILE 'myfile.csv'
ENDIF
FROM my_table;
```

Or do I just have to go with my current solution

```
SELECT *
-- INTO OUTFILE 'myfile.csv'
FROM my_table;
```

So always when I want to load data into file, I'll just uncomment "INTO"-line. My statements are way bigger than this example, so solution would make life much easier, if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating views and then export from the view to a file when needed, e.g.,

```
CREATE VIEW `query1` AS select * FROM my_table;

IF (@infile)
   SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'myfile.csv' FROM query1;
ELSE
   SELECT * FROM query1;
ENDIF
```

Comment: Unfortunately databases are mostly running with MySQL 4.1.9, so views are not supported.